# Permission-denied(publickey)

Tags: ssh

I searched on existing documents but nothing achieved.

From my laptop, I have to ssh to server A and from there I have to ssh again to have access to server B.

I tried below:

```
#ssh-add
#ssh -A username@serverA
```

then

```
#ssh username@serverB --> Permission denied (publickey).
```

again, from my laptop, I copied my `id.rsa` (private key) to serverA and from there ssh to serverB, while nothing happened too.

A brief output of ssh from serverA to serverB:

```
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
sent debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
received debug1: Roaming not allowed by server debug1:
SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey debug1: Next
authentication method: publickey debug1: Offering RSA public key:
/home/moji/.ssh/id_rsa debug1: Authentications that can continue:
publickey debug1: Offering RSA public key: M.Taleghani debug1:
Authentications that can continue: publickey debug1: Trying private
key: /home/mojtaba/.ssh/id_rsa debug1: Trying private key:
/home/mojtaba/.ssh/id_dsa debug1: Trying private key:
/home/mojtaba/.ssh/id_ecdsa debug1: Trying private key:
/home/mojtaba/.ssh/id_ed25519 debug1: No more authentication methods
to try. Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: I read it before. the problem exist yet

Comment: Your procedure's not really clear , but I think you shoud copy _to ServerB_ the **ServerA** `id.rsa` and **not** your laptop one.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `echo "${HOSTNAME:-"$(hostname)"}: $SSH_AUTH_SOCK"; ssh-add -l; ssh -vA username@serverA sh -c 'echo "${HOSTNAME:-"$(hostname)"}: $SSH_AUTH_SOCK"; ssh-add -l; ssh -v username@serverB'`? Thanks.